# How do I convert an Active Directory objectGuid to a readable string?

Tags: mobile, encoding, active-directory, ldap, xamarin

I'm using `Novell.Directory.Ldap` in a Xamarin mobile application, written in C#.

Using Novell, I am able to authenticate a user based on domain, username, and password using

```
LdapConnection.bind(username, password);
```

Then, I perform a search, using the `sAMAccountName`, which is equivalent to the supplied username.

After all this, which works successfully, I need to get the user's `objectGuid` so that I can query external databases, which use that guid as a key. The problem is, when I get the guid back form the `LdapSearchResults`, it's encoded somehow. And I cannot figure out how to get the readable string representation of this guid.

Does anyone have more information on this? I would imagine that the guid is encoded somehow, but how it's encoded, I do not know. I have tried

```
System.Convert.FromBase64String
```

and that didn't help. I appreciate the help guys, let me know if I can post anymore information that'd be helpful.

```
private void Login()
{
    if (LOG.isInfoEnabled())
    {
        LOG.info("Attempting LDAP logon . . .");

        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            LOG.debug("Host: " + this.ldapHost);
            LOG.debug("Port: " + this.ldapPort);
            LOG.debug("SearchBase: " + this.ldapSearchBase);
        }
    }

    LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection();

    try
    {
        conn.Connect(this.ldapHost, this.ldapPort);

        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            LOG.debug("connected?: " + conn.Connected.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOG.error("An exception occurred while attempting to connect to AD server!", e);

        // INFORM USER ABOUT ERROR
        authError(Resource.String.error_unknown);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.editTextUserName.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.editTextPassword.Text))
    {
        // HIDE KEYBOARD
        var imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextPassword.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.NotAlways);

        // HIDE 'LOGON' BUTTON WHILE LOGGING ON
        this.buttonLogin.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

        try
        {
            // PERFORM AUTHENTICATION
            conn.Bind(this.userName, this.userPassword);

            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
            {
                LOG.debug("conn.Bound?: " + conn.Bound);
            }

            if (conn.Bound)
            {
                if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
                {
                    LOG.debug("authentication successful");
                }

                string[] name = this.userName.Split('\\');
                LOG.debug("name[0]: " + name[0]);
                LOG.debug("name[1]: " + name[1]);

                string filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + name[1] + ")";
                string guid = "";

                LdapSearchResults searchResults = conn.Search(
                    this.ldapSearchBase, // search base
                    LdapConnection.SCOPE_SUB, // search scope  
                    filter, // filter
                    null, // attributes
                    false); // attributes only

                while (searchResults.hasMore())
                {
                    LdapEntry nextEntry = null;

                    try
                    {
                        nextEntry = searchResults.next();
                        guid = nextEntry.getAttribute("objectGUID").StringValue;
                    }
                    catch (LdapException e)
                    {
                        LOG.error("An exception occurred while attempting to get next search result!", e);
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(DashboardActivity));
                intent.PutExtra("guid", guid);

                StartActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                // INFORM USER ABOUT ERROR
                authError(Resource.String.error_auth);
            }
        }
        catch (LdapException ldape)
        {
            LOG.error("An exception occurred while attempting to authenticate user credentials!", ldape);

            // INFORM USER ABOUT ERROR
            authError(Resource.String.error_auth);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Disconnect();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        conn.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: You say that you are able to bind using domain and username. How exactly are you formatting this? I'm having trouble with my bind. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30773555/3799847

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure if the Novell library encodes it in some other way, but System.DirectoryServices provides the GUID as a byte array. You can get this to a readable string using the System.Guid struct:

```
new Guid((System.Byte[])this.GUID).ToString()
```

Answer (score 8):

The **ObjectGUID** is a binary string ( or octet string ), so what you are probably seeing is some random nonsense characters when you attempt display the value.

The **ObjectGUID** actually follows a well-established standard - it's a [UUID version 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29).
Since I do not work with *C#* I cannot provide working example, but with this information, you should be able to decode the binary string into a readable string representation or at least find a working code example. I have a strong suspicion that there will be some native class or a library to work with UUIDs / Guids in *C#*.

If you don't mind reading a php example, take a look at [my implementation](https://github.com/Alaneor/AD-X/blob/master/ADX/Core/Converter.php#L263) of the conversion in php.

Here's the function in question. It expects the $guid in its original binary form as returned from server.

```
function _to_p_guid( $guid )
{
$hex_guid = unpack( "H*hex", $guid );
$hex    = $hex_guid["hex"];

$hex1   = substr( $hex, -26, 2 ) . substr( $hex, -28, 2 ) . substr( $hex, -30, 2 ) . substr( $hex, -32, 2 );
$hex2   = substr( $hex, -22, 2 ) . substr( $hex, -24, 2 );
$hex3   = substr( $hex, -18, 2 ) . substr( $hex, -20, 2 );
$hex4   = substr( $hex, -16, 4 );
$hex5   = substr( $hex, -12, 12 );

$guid = $hex1 . "-" . $hex2 . "-" . $hex3 . "-" . $hex4 . "-" . $hex5;

return $guid;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a 404 for that. Do you by any chance have your php implementation elsewhere? I'm currently having issues with this returning the wrong guid: echo bin2hex($user_info['objectguid'][0]);

Comment: I have updated the link ( I recently moved the source code around a bit ) and provided the sample code in question directly in the answer. My apologies!

Answer (score 2):

In the Novell library, `objectGUID` is an `SByte` array, which needs to be cast to a `Byte` array before being converted to a `GUID`. You also need to get the `ByteValue` of `objectGUID`, rather than the `StringValue`.

```
try
{
    nextEntry = searchResults.next();
    guid = new Guid((Byte[])(Array)nextEntry.getAttribute("objectGUID").ByteValue);
}
catch (LdapException e)
{
    LOG.error("An exception occurred while attempting to get next search result!", e);
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to instantiate a GUID in the following manner:

```
internal string GetProperty(SearchResult searchResult, String PropertyName)
{
    string retVal = string.Empty;
    if (searchResult.Properties.Contains(PropertyName))
    {
        if (PropertyName == "objectguid")
        {
            Guid _guid = new Guid((Byte[])(Array)searchResult.Properties[PropertyName][0]);
            retVal = _guid.ToString();
        }
        else
            retVal = searchResult.Properties[PropertyName][0].ToString();        }
    return retVal;
}
```